# ERROR: Build process returned exit code 137 during Docker build on Tutum

Tags: docker, tutum

I've set a new repository on Tutum linked to a Github repository. This project built successfully on my local machine but it fail on Tutum after 4 hours and give me the following logs.

```
Step 27 : ENTRYPOINT /www/run.sh
---> Running in 666e1e87a660
---> eeb9646f9317
Removing intermediate container 666e1e87a660
Successfully built eeb9646f9317
Creating builder1769_sut_1
[Thu Jan 07 17:42:45.675789 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.5.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 07 17:42:45.675813 2016] [core:notice] [pid 8] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
ERROR: Build process returned exit code 137
builder-1769: Terminating...
builder-1769: Terminated
ERROR: Build in 'dockerize' (bcf1bce8) failed in 4:00:52
```

The final step 27 of my Dockerfile has been reached and Docker return the message "Successfully built eeb9646f9317" but also "ERROR: Build process returned exit code 137" just after.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.5-apache

#Add Servername to avoid warning
RUN sed -i '/ServerName localhost/ d' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf && sed -i '/Listen 80/ a\ServerName localhost' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

#Add apt packages list for Firefox
RUN echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -q -y --force-yes libpng-dev php5-imagick php5-curl php5-mysql php5-ssh2 vim wkhtmltopdf curl nodejs npm nodejs-legacy ruby-full default-jre firefox xvfb  \
    git zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ libmcrypt-dev libxml2-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -sSL https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd zip pdo_mysql soap mbstring intl mcrypt bcmath \
    && a2enmod expires headers rewrite \
    && pecl install apcu-4.0.10 \
    && php5enmod mcrypt pdo_mysql \
    && echo "date.timezone=Europe/Paris" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "short_open_tag=Off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "memory_limit=-1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "upload_max_filesize=6M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "extension=apcu.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

#Firefox
ENV FIREFOX_MINOR 34.0.5
RUN [ -e /usr/bin/firefox ] && rm /usr/bin/firefox
ADD https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/${FIREFOX_MINOR}/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-${FIREFOX_MINOR}.tar.bz2 /tmp/
RUN apt-get install -q -y libdbus-glib-1-2
RUN tar -xvjf /tmp/firefox-${FIREFOX_MINOR}.tar.bz2 -C /opt/
RUN chmod -R +x /opt/firefox/
RUN ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox

ADD .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/wweeddoo.conf
RUN a2ensite wweeddoo.conf
RUN sed -i '/DocumentRoot \/var\/www\/html/ d' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN sed -i 's/var\/www/www/g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

ADD . /www
WORKDIR /www

# Install dependencies
RUN mkdir -p app/sessions var/cache var/logs
RUN chown -R www-data app/sessions var/cache var/logs
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN npm install -g less
RUN gem install sass
RUN composer config -g github-oauth.github.com ff040c19e1b0ae0a4b97c0a140272ec89c8da161
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist

# Add run script
ADD .docker/run.sh /www/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /www/run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/www/run.sh"]
```

And my run.sh

```
chown -R www-data var/cache var/logs app/sessions
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

Any idea ?

Comment: post your Dockerfile or a link ot it.

Answer (score 25):

In Mac, to tackle with it, you might want to try changing memory allocation in Docker > Preference > Memory. Mostly increase will work.

Answer (score 4):

I found that this happens most of the time when the server runs out of resources and mostly memory.
You have 2 options.

1. If this is a staging server, then you can afford to shut down the services with `docker-compose down`. Then build your containers, `docker-compose build` and once that is through, restart your server `docker-compose up -d`. `-d` is for "detached" from your terminal.
2. If this is a production server, depending on which service you are on, you can increase the memory of the `docker-machine` you are using and then build your containers.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers above are correct.

However, today I discovered another case (my bad), I was on the wrong context. Even if I increased the RAM I still had the same error. So always verify that the context you are on is correct.

```bash
❯ docker context ls
NAME                 DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                    KUBERNETES ENDPOINT                 ORCHESTRATOR
default              Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                        https://127.0.0.1:59074 (default)   swarm
desktop-linux *                                                unix:///Users/mateonunez/.docker/run/docker.sock
```

And just change your context.

```bash
❯ docker context use default
default
Current context is now "default"
```

I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, if you are using the latest docker version, please do the below.

Docker => Preferences... => Docker Engine => change the experimental feature like below. Here I have mentioned as 30GB you can increase based on your need.

```
    {
      "experimental": false,
      "builder": {
        "gc": {
          "enabled": true,
          "defaultKeepStorage": "30GB"
        }
      },
      "features": {
        "buildkit": false
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Docker build kit. By preceding the build command with DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).