# Error 137 when build docker image locally from node app on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, image, docker, ubuntu-20.04

i'm having a trouble when i build a docker image locally. This is the build

```
   FROM node 
   WORKDIR /home/node/unqfy
   COPY package.json .
   COPY package-lock.json .
   RUN ["npm", "install"]
   EXPOSE 5001
   COPY . /home/node/unqfy/
   RUN chown -R 777 /home/node/unqfy
   CMD [ "node", "./src/API/requests/router.js" ]
```

Obviusly it's a node app. But when it comes to the `npm install` line it returns a 137 error, which implies that it reaches the RAM limit as investigated. The thing is that i use Ubuntu 20.04 and, unlike windows, it is not necessary to specify how much memory docker can use, it is dynamic and therefore there is not a config for that in ubuntu. I couldnt find anything refered to this error given in the image build process, contrary when a container is setted up, this error is much less common. I run the `docker info` command an saw that the Total Memory part have all the RAM that i have in my system. Previously i change the default directory where docker allocate images to a completly different partition, i am using the /mnt/UNQ/docker-final/ directory and i configure the root-dir param in the daemon.json file whit that path. I've done that 'cause i am running out of storage in the partition where docker stores the images by default.

Comment: Since you copy in the `package-lock.json`, try [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci) instead.

Comment: I did it but got the same error: The command 'npm ci' returned a non-zero code: 137
The terminal process "zsh '-c', 'docker build --pull --rm -f "UNQfy-Service/Dockerfile" -t service:unqfy "UNQfy-Service"'" terminated with exit code: 137.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40108478/4482269

Comment: Is there any more of the build output than what you quote?  Is there at least partial output from the `npm install` step?

Comment: No David, it doesn't show any more info than that, i search for the way to show more details from the logs of the process but i couldn't find any command for that. The worst part is that the service itself runs perfectly, the thing is when i want to built an image for it